# select only a word that is part of colon

Tags: grep

I have a text file using markup language (similar to wikipedia articles)

```
cat test.txt
This is a sample text having: colon in the text. and there is more [[in single or double: brackets]]. I need to select the first word only.
and second line with no [brackets] colon in it.
```

I need to **select the word "having:" only** because that is part of regular text. I tried

```
grep -v '[*:*]' test.txt
```

This will correctly avoid the tags, but does not select the expected word.

Comment: Do you just want to find the first word with a colon (`:`)?  Does that word always end with a colon?

Comment: yes. That is correct. But it should not be tagged (i mean in [])

Comment: not just the first word, but all "untagged" words ending with colon.

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Your regex is obviously flawed but it's not clear what you expect the output to be. Are you trying to say you want to match colons (or colons and the words adjacent to them?), but only when they are not inside square brackets? (What then if there is an unpaired opening bracket, for example?) Please [edit] to indicate expected output as well as probably some demonstration of actually reading the `grep` manual page.

Comment: Why do you mention brackets a couple of times in your example when there's no obvious reason to consider them in any way different from any other character? Please [edit] your question to include more than just the 1 sunny-day input example. Add cases where `:`s exist but you do NOT want the preceding "word" selected. Add cases where `::`s exist, etc. It's always easy to match the string you want but much harder to not match similar (or additional) strings you don't want. Also make sure to show the expected output given whatever input you post.

Comment: When you say in your sample input `I need to select the first word only` - explain why. Is it because you always only want 1 word per line printed or because the 2nd one is inside square brackets or because it's inside double square brackets or something else? So we can help you, please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and provide more comprehensive sample input/output that covers your requirements and we can copy/paste to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combined solution using `sed` and `awk`:

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' test.txt | gawk 'i==0 && $0~/:$/{ print $0 }/\[/{ i++} /\]/ {i--}'
```

- `sed` will change all spaces to a newline
- `awk` (or gawk) will output all lines matching `$0~/:$/`, as long as `i` equals zero
- The last part of the awk stuff keeps a count of the opening and closing brackets.

Another solution using `sed` and `grep`:

```
sed -r -e 's/\[.*\]+//g' -e 's/ /\n/g' test.txt  | grep ':$'
```

- `'s/\[.*\]+//g'` will filter the stuff between brackets
- `'s/ /\n/g'`  will replace a space with a newline
- grep will only find lines ending with `:`

A third on using only `awk`:

```
gawk '{ for (t=1;t<=NF;t++){ 
            if(i==0 && $t~/:$/) print $t; 
            i=i+gsub(/\[/,"",$t)-gsub(/\]/,"",$t) }}' test.txt
```

- `gsub` returns the number of replacements.
- The variable `i` is used to count the level of brackets. On every `[` it is incremented by 1, and on every `]` it is decremented by one. This is done because `gsub(/\[/,"",$t)` returns the number of replaced characters. When having a token like `[[][` the count is increased by (3-1=) 2.  When a token has brackets AND a semicolon my code will fail, because the token will match, if it ends with a `:`, before the count of the brackets.

Comment: Awk can do everything `sed` can so this could easily be refactored to pure Awk.

Comment: @tripleee: added a `awk` only option.

Comment: I deleted the `gsub()` which was indeed useless...

Comment: The pure Awk solution could do with a bit of explanation. My reading of it is that it will count the number of opening brackets and closing brackets in each token, but this will produce odd results if the token contains both an opening bracket and a colon, and if the brackets in the file are not perfectly paired.

Comment: @tripleee: I do hope my explanation, which I just added) is clear.

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets specify a character class, so your regular expression looks for any occurrence of one of the characters `*` or `:` (or `*`, but we said that already, didn't we?)

`grep` has the option `-o` to only print the matching text, so something lie

```
grep -ow '[^[:space:]]*:[^[:space:]]*' file.txt
```

would extract any text with a colon in it, surrounded by zero or more non-whitespace characters on each side.  The `-w` option adds the condition that the match needs to be between word boundaries.

However, if you want to restrict in which context you want to match the text, you will probably need to switch to a more capable tool than plain `grep`.  For example, you could use `sed` to preprocess each line to remove any bracketed text, and *then* look for matches in the remaining text.

```
sed -e 's/\[.*]//g' -e 's/ [^: ]*$/ /' -e 's/[^: ]* //g' -e 's/ /\n/' file.txt
```

(This assumes that your `sed` recognizes `\n` in the replacement string as a literal newline. There are simple workarounds available if it doesn't, but let's not go there if it's not necessary.)

In brief, we first replace any text between square brackets. (This needs to be improved if your input could contain multiple sequences of square brackets on a line with normal text between them. Your example only shows nested square brackets, but my approach is probably too simple for either case.) Then, we remove any words which don't contain a colon, with a special provision for the last word on the line, and some subsequent cleanup. Finally, we replace any remaining spaces with newlines, and (implicitly) print whatever is left. (This still ends up printing one newline too many, but that is easy to fix up later.)

Alternatively, we could use `sed` to remove any bracketed expressions, then use `grep` on the remaining tokens.

```
sed -e :a -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//' -e ta file.txt |
grep -ow '[^[:space:]]*:[^[:space:]]*'
```

The `:a` creates a label `a` and `ta` says to jump back to that label and try again if the regex matched. This one also demonstrates how to handle nested and repeated brackets. (I suppose it could be refactored into the previous attempt, so we could avoid the pipe to `grep`. But outlining different solution models is also useful here, I suppose.)

If you wanted to ensure that there is at least one non-colon character adjacent to the colon, you could do something like

```
... file.txt |
grep -owE '[^:[:space:]]+:[^[:space:]]*|[^[:space:]]*:[^: [:space:]]+'
```

where the `-E` option selects a slightly more modern regex dialect which allows us to use `|` between alternatives and `+` for one or more repetitions. (Basic `grep` in 1969 did not have these features at all; much later, the POSIX standard grafted them on with a slightly wacky syntax which requires you to backslash them to *remove* the literal meaning and select the metacharacter behavior... but let's not go there.)

Notice also how `[^:[:space:]]` matches a single character which is not a colon or a whitespace character, where `[:space:]` is the (slightly arcane) special POSIX named character class which matches any whitespace character (regular space, horizontal tab, vertical tab, possibly Unicode whitespace characters, depending on locale).

Awk easily lets you iterate over the tokens on a line. The requirement to ignore matches within square brackets complicates matters somewhat; you could keep a separate variable to keep track of whether you are inside brackets or not.

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
        if($i ~ /\]/) { brackets=0; next }
        if($i ~ /\[/) brackets=1;
        if(brackets) next;
        if($i ~ /:/) print $i }' file.txt
```

This again hard-codes some perhaps incorrect assumptions about how the brackets can be placed. It will behave unexpectedly if a single token contains a closing square bracket followed by an opening one, and has an oversimplified treatment of nested brackets (the first closing bracket after a series of opening brackets will effectively assume we are no longer inside brackets).